# If you have pressed charges against someone for violating a court order, is it legal for them to threaten you?

Tags: criminal-law, family-law, arizona

Let's assume the state is Arizona, both parties have 50/50 custody with a holiday custody exchange between 6pm-8:30pm. One parent (parent A) decided they don't want to see a child the previous year, but no verbal or written agreement exists to swap holidays. The following year, Parent A decides to abscond with the child during the 6pm-8:30pm holiday even after receiving a verbal warning (on camera) that parent B will press charges for violating a court order and custodial interference.

The police are called and they decide sufficient evidence exists to press charges.
Parent B agrees to press charges. The next day, parent B receives the following email from parent A:

"This is a formal request to have you stop texting and/or calling my phone. The court order states that primary contact is through email only regarding topics about _______. By court order you had 30 days to give me the television which I never received and pay me $1680.65 which I was only given half. A money order in the amount of $500 and another money order in the amount of $300 totaling $800. Formally requesting the remainder in the amount of $880.65 plus interest which is accruing at the legal rate. I am also formally requesting the TV (television must be in the same condition upon the separation or a new one will be provided). If not, the authorities will be contacted to retrieve these items. If you cease and desist and drop the charges associated with Halloween, I will let you have ______ on Thanksgiving Day to make up for a missed holiday. I want a formal letter drawn up and notarized stating that you are in agreement with this action by both parties. If not, we will proceed with the current situation.Thank you."

Has Parent A broken any laws by attempting to coerce parent B from dropping the charges?
What liabilities if any does parent B have assuming that the property has been returned and payments are being made?

Comment: Would not matter. If police are involved, it's a criminal matter of **The People Vs. so-and-so**.  A district attorney, representing the interests of **The People**, has decided the conduct is so egregious that **society itself** must be protected from that person. Alleged victims can't drop charges, they're not even making the charge. The DA is.  Parent B has no control over that criminal case, and a contractual agreement to drop charges is fraudulent on its face.  Parent B does not possess the item offered. They can offer to refuse to testify, but that's conspiracy to witness-tamper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two relevant laws. The first regards [threatening](https://www.azleg.gov/viewdocument/?docName=https://www.azleg.gov/ars/13/01202.htm), and involves physical injury / damage to person or property, or serious public inconvenience (e.g. bomb threats), none of which is applicable here. The second is [theft by extortion](https://www.azleg.gov/viewdocument/?docName=https://www.azleg.gov/ars/13/01804.htm), which involves obtaining property or services, by certain means. The first 4 means are irrelevant since they involve actions that are crimes, if committed. The part relevant here is

> 5. Accuse anyone of a crime or bring criminal charges against anyone.

The claim that the authorities will be contacted to retrieve the items is empty, because the authorities, once contacted, will say "Go to court and get a court order".

The accusation and bringing of criminal charges has apparently already happened, before any would-be threat was made. It is not illegal to notify a person that you will *not* drop charges (request the prosecutor or police to close this case). Under the letter of the law, the thing that you can't do is *threaten* to bring charges against them. And furthermore, the law offers a defense:

> B. It is a defense to a prosecution under subsection A, paragraph 5, 6
> or 7 of this section if a reasonable person would believe that the
> property or services were obtained or sought to be obtained by the
> threat of a reasonable accusation, exposure, lawsuit or other
> invocation of official action

which seems to be the case here (assuming that the letter correctly states the facts of the case).